# XDE:010 The emulator is unable to create a differencing disk

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, microsoft-emulator

After I reformat my computer and install Microsoft Emulator and Windows 10X Emulator,

The error shown as below:

[image]

and my settings.
[image]

any one facing the same issue?

Comment: is this question related to software development?

Comment: I hit the same error FYI. I'll try and dig up how we fixed it.

Comment: Can you confirm if you're on the latest Insider Fast build of Windows? We can't remember what fixed the issue on my machine.

Comment: Yes,I'm in the latest insider fast build.19564.rs_prerelease.200207-1438

Comment: And can you confirm that the file / directory isn't compressed or has EFS?

Comment: Could you check if  `Flash.vhdx` is complete, and have you tried to re-install Windows 10X emulator image. I install the emulator and launch it successful, and my os build version is 19564.1000.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure both the Microsoft Emulator app and the image package are installed on the C drive? Here's how:

- Go to Apps in the Windows Settings
- Search for Microsoft Emulator
- Click the "Move" button. If it's not on the C drive (or whatever you
  system drive is), move it there.

Now for the image...

- Click the "Advanced options" for Microsoft Emulator in the Apps settings
- Scroll down until you find the add-on for the image.
- Click the "Move" button and move it to the C drive (or whatever your system drive is) if it's not there.

Update:
The C drive also has to be uncompressed.

- Open File Explorer and right click on the C drive and click Properties
- Make sure this check box is unchecked: "Compress this drive to save space"

Comment: All in C Drive, also same

Comment: Have you tried to re-install Windows 10X emulator image?

Comment: Another thing to look for: is your C drive compressed? In File Explorer you can right click on C. click Properties and at the bottom there is a check box for "Compress this drive to save disk space". I think that has to be unchecked for virtual disks to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the update of Insider version 19569.1000